# Retrieve "Related Guest Payments" via Stripe API

Tags: stripe-payments

We have some customers that have 'related guest payments' instead of an actual payment since the charge didn't get linked up correctly on creation.  When retrieving the customers charges via the stripe api `stripe.Charge.list(customer_ID)` it doesnt return the 'related guest payments' since they are not technically part of that account.  The docs say that they are "grouped" into the customers view based on a matching field (i.e. credit card number).

Is it possible to retrieve ALL charges related to a customers account INCLUDING 'related guest payments'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stripe's [Guest Customers feature](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/guest-customers) is only available in the Dashboard. Stripe uses a variety of signal to determine if payments might be related such as the card's fingerprint, the email/billing details and such.

It's not possible to view Guest Customers details in the API in any way today. The only solution would be for you to list all your Charges and then try to find matches based on criteria similar to Stripe

Comment: Apparently you can manually 'attach' a related guest payment to a customer via the API by updating the customer id.  I might end up doing that for the largest payments that ended up as a 'related guest payment' to correct our spend metrics.